# JGit: How to get diff from multiple RevCommits?

Tags: git, jgit

I have a list of `RevCommits`, in chronological order, representing changes to a contiguous region of code, and all from the same file, and I want to get a `DiffEntry` or a String that represents the diff coming from all of these commits. Any suggestions?

My current attempt is using the `DiffCommand` with `.setNewTree(..)` and `.setOldTree(..)` to return a `List<DiffEntry>`, but I want to get the `DiffEntry`'s for my list of commits.

Comment: Are you looking at a continuous set of changes, i.e. all consecutive commits to a file over some time? Or rather some changes to the file, but some not?

Answer (score 3):

I have now added a snippet at the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowFileDiff.java) which shows how a diff of a file in between two commit-ids can be retrieved and also printed out similar to the git diff command.

If the commits are not continuous, I am not sure how to best select the changes, maybe you need to build a DiffEntry for each of the commits and use the resulting DiffEntrys for those.